# Moving every n files into a separate folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have several files with a repetitive naming convention, e.g.

```
1*Intro*
2*
3*
…
10*intro*
….
```

I want to move each module into a separate folder. So, I should separate from every `*intro*` till the next one.
Also, I should note that files are numbered and sorted.
I guess, the easiest way to do this is to:

```
1. Get a list of intros.
2. Separate their numbers.
3. Start moving files starting from one number till their smaller than the next one.


$i = 1
Ls *intro* | ft {$_.name -replace '\D.*', ''}
// The reason for .* is that the files are `mp4`.
Ls * | ? {$_.name -match '[^firstNumber-SecondNumber-1]'} | move-item -literalpath {$_.fullname} -destination $path + $i++ + '/' +{$_.name}
```

So the last command should be something like:

```
Ls *intro* | % { ls * | ? {…} | move-item … }
```

Or maybe the `move-item` itself can do the filtering job.

The regular expression doesn't work and I don't have enough Powershell knowledge to write anything better. Can you think of any script to do that? Also how should I permit `move-item` to create the folder?

I'll be thankful if someone could edit this post with a better title.

Comment: What are your files actually called? "*" is not a valid file name character.

Comment: It's a placeholder for any possible character! Usually just alphabetical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done with a simple `Switch`. The switch will be run against all items in the current folder (items gotten with the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet which you use by it's alias 'LS'). It looks to see if the file has the string "Intro" in the file name. If it does, it creates a new folder with that file's name, and stores that folder's info in the `$TargetFolder` variable (variable created previously to avoid scoping issues). It then moves the file to that folder, and continues to the next file. If the file does not have "Intro" in its file name it simply moves the file to whatever the last assigned `$TargetFolder` is that was created.

```psh
$TargetFolder = ""
Switch(Get-ChildItem .\*){
    {$_.BaseName -match "intro"} {$TargetFolder = New-Item ".\$($_.BaseName)" -ItemType Directory; Move-Item $_ -Destination $TargetFolder; Continue}
    default {Move-Item $TargetFolder}
}
```